# Good practice with equalities for non-class enums (rvalues on left?)

Tags: c, enumeration, rvalue

I work in an environment that is slowly updating old c to c++.  Frequently non-class enums are used within equality statements.

Now I'm sure anyone who has taken a programming course or read a book which covers good practice knows that equalities between lvalues and rvalues should be structured with the rvalue on the left to prevent accidental changes to data if '==' is substituted with '='.  I have never seen this done with enumerations.  The easy answer is to use enum class but this cannot always be immediately done with large bodies of older code.  Since an enum is basically just an integer, would it be considered good practice to do keep rvalues on the left for enumerations as well?

I wrote a small example to better illustrate below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int number;
    enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
int main() {
    number = 1234;
    Color color = BLUE;

    // This is done
    if ( 555 == number ) { /*...*/ }

    // So that this never accidently happens
    if ( number = 555 ) { /*...*/ }

    // Resulting in this (number changed to 555)
    cout << number <<endl;

    // I have never seen this done
    if ( RED == color  ) { /*...*/ }

    // should it be to, prevent this
    if ( color = RED ) { /*...*/ }

    //Resulting in this  (color changed to 0 or RED)
    cout << color <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are talking about the "Yoda style" comparisons, which some consider deprecated nowadays as the modern compilers have warnings about suspicious assignments. Some are disagreeing.

Comment: *"I'm sure anyone who has taken a programming course or read a book which covers good practice knows that equalities should be structured with the rvalue on the left to prevent accidental '='."* This is not true. And any decent compiler will trigger a warning for these cases anyway.

Comment: ^ *Quod Erat Demonstrandum* :)

Comment: Using gcc with -Wall, -Werror, or --pedantic does not generate warnings for this.  It wouldn't surprise me if there is a way of flagging this, but if it's a compiler flag that nobody thinks to use, wouldn't it make more sense to take this precaution?

Comment: @DanFeerst Tried `-Wextra`? So you are in the second camp. But both agree that you should be *consistent*.

Comment: BTW, it's a `-Wparentheses` switch, which is a part of `-Wall`. So it's weird you don't have it.

Comment: personally I don't do this (I think it looks weird and I don't like the sound of it in my head when I'm reading code), but steam isn't going to come out of my ears if I come across it. Plus I can't think of a time making this mistake has really burned me. I'd say do whatever you're comfortable with.

Comment: @yano I remember several extra hours at work at Friday night I have spent debugging  this kind of error. That was with some embedded (non-gcc) compiler and a poor debugger. Since then I am taking a very cautious position about the style.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you were just subconsciously really bored on Friday ;) Yeah thinking back I've always worked with good compilers I guess. I dunno, I've funneled many hours down the drain chasing stupid mistakes, but not this one, knock on wood. When I do get burned by this I'll strongly consider changing my ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it be considered good practice to do keep rvalues on the left for enumerations as well?

This is not precisely "good practice" even with literals, actually. This concept appeared in the past, but for most people having a literal on the right is much more readable (and also more consistent with the math notion that variables, specially ones that change the most, come first).

Trading off typo prevention for readability isn't always desirable. Readable code is in fact an old concept that has never changed and probably will never be. So at the end, stick with what makes more sense and is more easier to maintain. Preventing these kind of errors should be left to the compiler, and any decent compiler will trigger a warning in those cases.

Comment: While I completely agree that readability is important,  The problem is that in my situation, I might make a change to a 8000 line source file, which needs to be linked to 30 other files, in a repository maintained by many people, and older than I am.  Compilation takes an hour and a half using 30 cores. It's normal to see hundreds of warnings.  Of course that isn't a good thing but at the end of the day I need to worry about my code, not someone else's.

Comment: @DanFeerst I'm not sure if I understand your comment. What exactly is the problem, apart from considering normal seeing hundreds of warnings? Do you have to follow any project convention? And if so, why posting this question anyway?

Comment: Its preferred, but not enforced, and like I said, nobody does this with enums.  I was asking the question because I was curious what the most syntactic approach was. My curiosity came from recognizing it as something that could cause an issue in a large code base. I suppose your post does answer my question (+1), it just doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @DanFeerst I understand. Maybe the opinion of your co-workers will be valuable in this particular case. In a more generic sense, the most syntactic approach would be consistency with literals and other constants (an enum is just that anyway) and judging from the other reactions in your question I'd say use them on the right. However, above that, be consistent in your project. And please find a way to make those other programmers believe that seeing warnings is not normal! :D